# How do I get contents of UserControl from server using Jquery Ajax?

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, .net

The Asp.Net's ajax implementation using UpdatePanel is really slow and experienced people know that the whole ViewState is sent to server even though we are only interested in doing partial postback. So I started using Jquery but I don't know how do I make a request from Jauery to server and get UserControl's HTML in output? The UserControl in turn may have some controls like textbox etc.

In short, I want some functionality that Asp.Net MVC has which uses `RenderPartial`.

Comment: Are you reading values from viewstate on postback?  Are you aware that using jQuery to render the control after the page loads will cause the control to not be in the viewstate if you want to access it on postback?

Comment: OK. Thanks I was not aware of that. So what options do you suggest? Is there any way to speed up the Ajax?

Comment: How slow is the postback and render of your updatepanel? On gigantic pages I can still get pretty good responsiveness (<.5 seconds).  What is the purpose of the control? If it's read only, then AJAX is fine.

Comment: http://encosia.com/using-jquery-to-consume-aspnet-json-web-services/ see if this helps

Comment: for me it takes atleast 4 seconds that too for a simple task. The UserControl has country dropdown and state dropdown. On selection changed of country dropdown it makes a request to get states for that country. Apart from that, it just has few textboxes. When hosted on server, it takes atleast 4 seconds that too after the fact that both country and states are cached in memory. Approach suggested by mafue is perfect though it won't work in this situation.

Comment: Thanks Tom. I hope that method can be useful to you sometime in the future.

Comment: Sounds like your problem is the initial query of states relating to the country chosen?  If you are caching them after the first time they are requested why not move caching for all countries' states to the Application_Start event in global.asax? Unless you aren't caching data?

Comment: @EricH: It isn't the initial query that takes time. It's the ViewState hell. I moved the ViewState into Session and then it works pretty well. Problem is UpdatePanel submits all of the page's viewstate on server even though the only thing I am interested in updating is a small dropdown.

Comment: I am confused, why would you blame ViewState for slowness that an AJAX call would also experience given the bottleneck is the data query which isn't related to the ViewState?  As I've stated, I have updatepanels on pages with hundreds of controls and large viewstate and I am not hindered in the slightest by it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the context of `Page`, you can load a control and render its output.

```
Control myControl = Page.LoadControl("myControl.ascx");
myControl.RenderControl(System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter);
```

But that just gets the html that the control would output to the page. This is fine if your control has no more events and just does something onload, but if you want to postback from it, then this will not work (as mentioned in the comments.)

Answer (score 0):

From my experience, sometimes ago, trying to invoke a user control directly is a pain.

I sometimes put my userControl in a blank page and simply do a $.get(
So, for each userControl, I have to make a dedicated blank page...

Other times, the userControl is already embedded in an existing page within a named div container. I then invoke $.load( on the page, targetting the container div.
In this case, I don't have to make a page, but I waste bandwith and lose script and style tags (jQuery cleans them up since v1.4)

Comment: Please see mafue's answer. It is correct. Making methods (either WebMethods or static page methods) to serve usercontrols through Ajax are more better than making empty pages.

Comment: Usually a control is designed to follow a whole page lifecycle, including for example, parameters, binding and prerender. In this case, trying mafue's answer is the pain I was first talking about.